# weird error with Hibernate when trying to specify fields to retrieve

Tags: hibernate, hql

I was trying to specify the fields I want in an HQL (select). But when I do this, I keep on getting this weird problem.

**error message**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "staffId"
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:166)
    javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:46)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
    org.apache.jsp.views.search.SearchResults_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(SearchResults_jsp.java:209)
    org.apache.jsp.views.search.SearchResults_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(SearchResults_jsp.java:165)
    org.apache.jsp.views.search.SearchResults_jsp._jspService(SearchResults_jsp.java:96)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    org.apache.jsp.views.templates.Layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(Layout_jsp.java:344)
    org.apache.jsp.views.templates.Layout_jsp._jspService(Layout_jsp.java:182)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

**my HQL** (as you can see it's currently set to the one that gives me the error. but the one commented out works fine)

```
    //SQL = "from Staff where (surnameSearch is not null) and not (nvl(teleDirectory,'xxx') IN ('N','S','D')) and not (telephoneNumber IS NULL AND alias IS NULL) and (aliasList = 'Y' OR (teleDirectory IN ('A','B'))) and ((nvl(systemIdEnd,sysdate+1) > SYSDATE and entityType = 'P') or (entityType = 'N')) and (departmentSearch NOT like 'SPONSOR%')";
    SQL = "select staffId, parentId, entityType, title, firstname, surname, telephoneNumber, department, role from Staff where (surnameSearch is not null) and not (nvl(teleDirectory,'xxx') IN ('N','S','D')) and not (telephoneNumber IS NULL AND alias IS NULL) and (aliasList = 'Y' OR (teleDirectory IN ('A','B'))) and ((nvl(systemIdEnd,sysdate+1) > SYSDATE and entityType = 'P') or (entityType = 'N')) and (departmentSearch NOT like 'SPONSOR%')";
```

I've also tried this without any luck.

```
    SQL = "select staff.staffId, staff.parentId, staff.entityType, staff.title, staff.firstname, staff.surname, staff.telephoneNumber, staff.department, staff.role from Staff staff where (surnameSearch is not null) and not (nvl(teleDirectory,'xxx') IN ('N','S','D')) and not (telephoneNumber IS NULL AND alias IS NULL) and (aliasList = 'Y' OR (teleDirectory IN ('A','B'))) and ((nvl(systemIdEnd,sysdate+1) > SYSDATE and entityType = 'P') or (entityType = 'N')) and (departmentSearch NOT like 'SPONSOR%')";
```

**snippet of my model class**

```
public class Staff {
    Integer pk;
    String staffId;
    String parentId;
    String entityType;
    String title;
    String firstname;
    String surname;
    String telephoneNumber;
    String department;
    String role;

    String alias;
    String aliasList;
    String departmentSearch;
    String firstnameSearch;
    String roleSearch;
    String surnameSearch;
    String surnameLikeSearch;
    Date systemIdEnd;
    String teleDirectory;

    public Integer getPk() {
        return pk;
    }
    public void setPk(Integer pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    public String getStaffId() {
        return staffId;
    }
    public void setStaffId(String staffId) {
        this.staffId = staffId;
    }
```

**snippet of my hbm XML**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.flinders.staffdirectory.models.database.Staff" table="teld_summary">
        <id name="pk" column="telsumm_pk" />
        <property name="staffId" column="telsumm_id" />
```

**I've looked into my Oracle DB and confirmed that the "staffId" is indeed string (or varchar2 in my case).**

Can you please help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have mapped `staffid` to the column `telsumm_id`:

```
<property name="staffId" column="telsumm_id" />
```

It is likely that `telsumm_id` is an integer column, given its name ends in "_id"

Comment: I've already looked in my oracle table and the field is declared as varchar2.

Comment: Seems even though the field is declared as varchar2, there are no records with an ID that starts with a zero.

Comment: select count(*) from my_table_here
where substr(telsumm_id,1,1) = '0'

Comment: Could it be Hibernate trying to cast my field into integer even if I explicitly stated it is a string?